# How connect to Docker Container through docker-machine ip address?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to connect to my docker container..

My docker-machine ip is:

```
docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100

docker ps
b546f4666f01  richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:php5   "/start.sh"              2 days ago Up 2 days  443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp my_container
```

When I try to access in a browser: 
192.168.99.100:8080 doesn't resolve.  But I can access the container doing localhost:8080

Here's the docker + machine versions:

```
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
docker-machine version 0.15.0, build b48dc28d
```

I used to be able to directly access the container w/ the same network linking properties above w/ an older version.